# How to recursively scrape a web page to check if there are new pdf files in python?

Tags: python, screen-scraping

Theres a website which puts up a pdf report every month. I want to monitor it every hour and get the new pdf emailed to my email I'd whenever the new pdf gets uploaded. I want to use python for it. Also I'm familiar with beautiful soup and scrapy but I dont know how to check for new pdf files and only grab the new pdf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from time import strftime, sleep

# Here I Will Get The Current Month And Year And Assign It To Variables.

month = strftime("%B").lower()
year = strftime("%Y")

# I've noticed that the website publishing the file by the Month name in lower-case and year.
# Now we will loop on the url each one hour and download the file once released and exit.
# You Have to set cron-job to run every month.


while True:
    r = requests.get(
        f"http://www.pbs.gov.pk/sites/default/files//price_statistics/monthly_price_indices/nb/2019/cpi_review_nb_{month}_{year}.pdf")
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(f"{month}.pdf", 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
            print(f"File Already Saved As {month}.pdf")
            break
    else:
        print("File Not Raised Yet, We Will Check Back After One Hour.")
        sleep(3600)
        continue

# you can also put the current href links in a file.
# then loop over source and check if new href is released so download and append the href to file.
# but if the href in file so keep checking each hour.
```

Comment: The webpage already contains 4 pdfs as of now. It's going to add a new one in few days. How can I check if a specific pdf is a new one or not? I am familiar with cron jobs and while loops so I dont have any issues with them

Comment: @AdilSaleem well that's a good catch that you know the count of the current pdf files ! so all what you need to do, is iterating through the `href` which hold the link for the pdf. and if it's `> 4` So download and `exit` the loop.

Comment: oh that makes sense. lets say that the website uploaded the new pdf and i somehow get notified. how can i make sure that the script grabs only the new pdf and emails me that only?

Comment: i cant. i have written the code using a text file to record number of pdf files. however would you suggest comparing the hash values of the web pages to get updated?

Comment: @AdilSaleem you can do it by easyway. hold on let me share for you an example.

Comment: thanks alot bro. the problem i am facing right now is how can i store vairables for next session? i want to run this script once a day and it will compare the meta data with the previous day meta data but how would i get the previous day meta data?

Comment: also url is http://www.pbs.gov.pk/cpi-nb. you can see that there are 4 pdfs files as of right now and the fourth one will get updated in few days.

Comment: i checked it out the code, but the problem sometimes that website uses some random names for the pdf. you wont be able to figure out a pattern

Comment: @AdilSaleem then you have to apply the last 3 lines which I've wrote.